# checking if a certain many to many foreign key is present on django-polymorphic models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-polymorphic

So in order to create an object model, I have to first see if a supplier has a relation of type many to many from BusinessModel, WarehouseModel or StoreModel to  in a django-polymorphic

My main idea is to check if BusinessModel, which is connected to Order through BusinessOrderModel, StoreModel, which is connected to Order through StoreOrderModel or WarehouseModel which is connected directly to Order, have FKs on a many to many relationship going to the article that we want to order through a POST request.

```
class ArticleModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.code)

class OrderModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_to = models.ForeignKey('OrderToModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey('ArticleModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity= models.IntegerField()

class OrderToModel(PolymorphicModel):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class WarehouseModel(OrderToModel):
    warehouse_num = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleModel)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Warehouse"+ str(self.warehouse_num)

class StoreOrderModel(OrderToModel):
    reference = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    store_num = models.ForeignKey('StoreModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reference)

class StoreModel(models.Model):
    store_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleModel)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.store_num)

class BusinessOrderModel(OrderToModel):
    reference = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    business_num = models.ForeignKey('BusinessModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.reference)
    
class BusinessModel(models.Model):
    Business_num = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.TextField()
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleModel)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.Business_num)
```

Here's my serializers:

```
class WarehouseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WarehouseModel
        fields = ('id', 'warehouse_num')


class StoreOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StoreOrderModel
        fields = ('id', 'reference', 'store_num')


class DetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DetailModel
        fields = ('id', 'detail')

class BusinessOrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = DetailSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BusinessOrderModel
        fields = ('reference', 'business_num','details')

class OrderToPolymorphicSerializer(PolymorphicSerializer):
    model_serializer_mapping = {
        WarehouseModel: WarehouseSerializer,
        StoreOrderModel: StoreOrderSerializer,
        BusinessOrderModel: BusinessOrderSerializer
    }
```

and here's my view:

```
class OrderCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = OrderModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderCreateSerializer
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I'm trying to be able to only create an OderModel instance if the foreign key pointing to article on BusinessModel for business instances, StoreModel in Store instances or WarehouseModel on warehouse instances has an FK on a many to many field pointing to an article